# Disconnecting a mail washer and emails bouncing

Tags: linux, email, dns, exim

A few days ago suddenly all incoming emails for several domains on my Centos 7.x server were being bounced and still are; outgoing email was and is still working.  We suspect a cPanel update might be the cause as no other changes had been made.  These domains have been using a mail washer service, and we (me, my hosting provider, and mail washer staff)  couldn't determine the cause.

So for the most importand domain (example.com)  I decided to bypass the mail washer and live with the spam at least temporarily.  So I deleted the MX records pointing to the mail washer and cut down to one MX record pointng to our local mail server, and restarted ExIm.

> 14400 0 mail.example.com

I verified that the DNS change was working using dig, and the mail washer was no longer getting that email. But still all incoming email is bouncing for all domains.

The bounce message says that the domain couldn't be found and "please use the proper MX record"; but the website works well and MXToolbox says all looks OK.  Any ideas on what to check next in order to get incoming email to example.com?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a cPanel update garbled some files/settings, plus removing example.com from the /etc/filterdomains file followed by restarting ExIm.  Such resolved the issues with all domains.  Hope this helps someone else.